# Why data type converted from BIGNUMERIC to FLOAT32 after export parquet files from Bigquery?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, parquet

I exported a table from bigquery and faced a problem that was there is one column with `BIGNUMERIC` type, after exported and read on pandas using fastparquet, the data type for this column changed from `BIGNUMERIC` to `FLOAT32`.
For example: the original value is 950000000000000000000.00000000000000000000000000000000000000, and the value after reading by fastparquet: -4.5957913492186725e-20

Could the reason for this be due to exporting from bigquery to parquet file? Or the fastparquet library made it wrong?

I've tried to use pyarrow instead but another error was: `ArrowInvalid: Decimal precision out of range [1, 76]: 77`

Comment: Could please someone confirm follwing error: I created a table in BigQuery with a large value (9.5E+20). Then exported this table to GCS as parquet. An inport of this file to BigQuery fails with: 

Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Input file is not in Parquet format. File: gs://test....

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery's Bignumeric data type technically allows a partial [77th digit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#decimal_types) which is why parquet exports set the precision to 77.   Fastparquet documentation states larger precision [decimal types will overflow](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#data-types), and the precision/scale of bignumeric are far outside the range of floating point values.  As Arrow's error message indicates, it does not support a partial 77th digit.  One workaround for allowing the field to be read by arrow is to specify [type parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#parameterized_decimal_type) on the BigQuery schema if you don't need the partial 77th digit. Alternatively loading the data frame via the BigQuery storage API should work if no values rely on the 77th partial digit